# c# why will chrome not let me hide it with user32.dll ShowWindow()

Tags: c#, google-chrome, user32

I'm starting chrome with the code below.

```
Process OpenYouTube                = new Process();
Chrome.StartInfo.FileName          = "chrome.exe";
Chrome.StartInfo.WindowStyle       = System.Diagnostics.ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
Chrome.Start();
```

And then using the code below to attempt to hide it.

```
[DllImport("user32.dll")]
static extern bool ShowWindow(IntPtr hWnd, int nCmdShow);

const int SW_HIDE = 0;
const int SW_SHOW = 5;

HideProcessAndChildren(Chrome.Id);

private void HideProcessAndChildren(int pid)
{
    ManagementObjectSearcher searcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher("Select * From Win32_Process Where ParentProcessID=" + pid);
    ManagementObjectCollection moc = searcher.Get();
    foreach (ManagementObject mo in moc)
    {
        HideProcessAndChildren(Convert.ToInt32(mo["ProcessID"]));
    }
    try
    {
        Process proc = Process.GetProcessById(pid);
        ShowWindow(proc.MainWindowHandle, SW_HIDE);
    }
    catch (ArgumentException ex)
    {
        // Process already exited.
    }
}
```

This code works fine for notepad etc but Chrome refuses to be hidden.

How can I hide it once launched or when launched? I am aware of selenium etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You won't be able to do it in the manner you are attempting.

You can look into using ChromeDriver and try something like:

```
var chromeDriverService = ChromeDriverService.CreateDefaultService();
chromeDriverService.HideCommandPromptWindow = true;
return new ChromeDriver(chromeDriverService,  new ChromeOptions());
```

Comment: Thanks for the input Patrick, could you elaborate why please :-)

Comment: @jamie Do a Google search for "C# hide chrome" or "ChromeDriver hide chrome", you should get more information.